# How to fetch the saved drop down value from db and bind the saved value to drop down using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have a drop down with select where i can set the default value for that drop down which was done and next time when user lands on that page i need to display that saved drop down

Html

```
<select id="ddlValue" onchange="OnChange()" style="height: 25px;padding: 2px 12px;font-size: 12px;color: #555;background-color: #fff;background-image: none;border: 1px solid #ccc;width:15%;" class="ItemPT5">
                        <option value="0">All</option>
                        <option value="2">Value1</option>
                        <option value="1">Value2</option>
                        <option value="3">Value3</option>
</select>
```

Jquery code-

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: webAPIURL + '/GetLoggedinuserId?MemberId=' + UserId,
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                traditional: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {   //getting all the data from controller 
                    if (data.length > 0) {  //since length will be greater than 0 it satisfies if conditon
                        $.each(data.d, function () {
                            $("#ddlValue").append($("<option/>").val(this.KeyName).text(this.ValueName));  //unable to bind selected value to drop down
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
```

Database-

```
ID              DDL_TYPE        SELECTED
1                value1         true  //should bind value 1 to drop down using jquery since this is saved against the user
2                value2             false
3                value3         false
```

Controller-

```
public string GetLoggedinuserId(int MemberId)
        {
            try
            {
                esParameters EsPm = new esParameters();
                DataTable dt = null;
                EsPm.Add(new esParameter("ID", MemberId));
                dt = EsPm.FillDataTable("USP_GET");
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { ex.LogException(); return null; }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: can anybody help me out

Comment: you want how to fetch data from database ? or just bind data to your dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model

```
public class DropdownModel{
    public int Value {get; set;}
    public string Text {get; set;}
    public bool IsSelected {get; set;}
}
```

Controller

```
//add below namespace
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

//method returns Json string
public string GetLoggedinuserId(int MemberId)
        {
            try
            {
                esParameters EsPm = new esParameters();
                DataTable dt = null;
                EsPm.Add(new esParameter("ID", MemberId));
                dt = EsPm.FillDataTable("USP_GET");
                //Convert DataTable to List
                List<DropdownModel> list = new List<DropdownModel>();
                //Iterate DataTable Rows and Add to List
                foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)  
                {  
                     list.Add(new DropdownModel(){
                           Value = dr["ID"],
                           Text = dr["DDL_TYPE"],
                           IsSelected = dr["SELECTED"]
                     });

                }
                //Create JavaScriptSerializer object
                var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                //Convert list to Json string
                var jsonString = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(list);
               //returns list as JsonString
               return jsonString;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { 
                 ex.LogException();  
                 return null;
             }
             return null;
        }
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
      var options = '';
      $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: webAPIURL + '/GetLoggedinuserId?MemberId=' + UserId,
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                traditional: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {   //getting all the data from controller          //data is not null
                    if (data != null) {  //since length will be greater than 0 it satisfies if conditon
                         //parse Json string and iterate 
                         $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (i,v) {
                             //if user selected this option add selected attribute to option
                             var selected = v.IsSelected == true ? "selected": "";
                             //add options
                             options += "<option value="+ v.Value+" "+ selected +">"+ v.Text+"</option>";
                        });
                         //clear dropdown options
                         $("#ddlValue").empty();
                        //append options
                        $("#ddlValue").append(options)
                    }
                }
            });
});
```

Html

```
<select id="ddlValue" onchange="OnChange()" style="height: 25px;padding: 2px 12px;font-size: 12px;color: #555;background-color: #fff;background-image: none;border: 1px solid #ccc;width:15%;" class="ItemPT5">
      <option value="0">All</option>
      <option value="2">Value1</option>
      <option value="1">Value2</option>
      <option value="3">Value3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: check return and remove Json(null, JsonBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: I tried this code is working but the issue is in html  i am showing only 4 values in drop down as all,value1,value2,value3 but in db i have value1,value2,value3,value4,value5 while binding it is fetching the db drop down values instead of fetching html drop down values